# How to include the coffee-script module in node using Cygwin on Windows

Tags: node.js, cygwin, coffeescript

I'm trying to get the functionality of CoffeeScript.compile in node.js.

I've installed node on Cygwin in Windows, and installed coffee script with npm.

I can use the coffee command fine but if I try to

```
require("coffee-script");
```

I get "Cannot find module 'coffee-script'" in node.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like `require` isn't looking in npm's global install path. Run

```
require.paths
```

from the Node REPL to see which paths are being looked in. On the command line, run

```
npm ls -g
```

to see the directory that `npm` is installing global libraries in (it's `/usr/local/lib` on my Mac). Add `/node_modules` to that, and add it to `require.paths`. You can do this on a one-time basis by running

```
require.paths.shift('/usr/local/lib/node_modules');
```

(**Update:** Modifying `require.paths` is no longer allowed as of Node 0.5+.)

or you can do it permanently by adding the line

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: No problem. Getting Node and npm up and running can be tricky. I talk about it a little in my [CoffeeScript book](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript).

Comment: I'm using Oh My Zsh.  To get this to work, I had to add quotations around the value of `NODE_PATH`: `export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules"`

Answer (score 1):

Are you using from a different directory? If so, install it globally with the -g flag. 
(npm install coffee-script -g).

Comment: I've tried re-installing with the -g flag, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with the -g flag and just using require("coffee-script"), however if I gave an absolute path it now works.